# Как сделать backup на Git?

Tags: git, git-commit, резервное-копирование, git-branch

Вот разбираюсь с `Git` и такой вопрос... У нас есть локальные ветки и удаленные.

Удаленная у меня называется `master` по умолчанию и я создал еще одну локальную и назвал ее `develop`.

Теперь мне нужно разработать новую фичу и я создаю еще одну локальную ветку и называю ее `feature`, делаю  в ней все что нужно и когда понимаю, что все готово, то я ее сливаю в локальную ветку `develop` и удаляю ее.

И что получается у нас есть локальная ветка `develop` с новой фичей и удаленная ветка `master` которая не знает о изменениях...

Но в мастер я сливать ветку `develop` не могу так как в мастер я сливаю уже релизные версии, значит мне нужно создать удалено еще ветку `remoteDev` и сливать все изменения в нее, а когда все протестируется то уже эту удаленную ветку `remoteDev` слить в `master` и получить релиз...

Верно я понимаю? Я просто раньше не пользовался гитом...

Comment: Вам абсолютно никто не мешает держать develop удаленно. И не нужно его называть remoteDev. Более того, держать много веток - это нормально. Даже более того. Нужна новая фича - сделали ветку, закомитили в нее, запушили ветку удаленно. Продолжаете дальше работать в ветке и пушите в нее. А смерждить в этом случае можно будет и с другой машины. Даже другим человеком. А если ветки держать только локально, то их легко потерять.

Comment: в [описании метки git](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) перечислено немного литературы. обратите внимание на руководство «удачная модель ветвления».

Comment: вспомнил статью по ветвлению в git http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос, у вас сомнения по поводу слияния веток и их взаимодействия. Но ваши мысли идут в верном направлении.
В простейшем случае это выглядит так:

```
локальные ветки - master (релиз), develop...
удаленные ветки (на сервере) - master (релиз), develop...
```

Но никто вам не запрещает делать больше веток, тем более хорошим тоном считается для любого фикса (или нового функционала, или релиза) делать отдельную ветку и проверять его работоспособность в ней.

Все изменения, новый фичи, баги должны проводиться через ветку develop, так как master считается стабильной в любом коммите. В master ветку отправляют только готовые релизы с оттестированным функционалом, ну, или срочные баги.

Слияние веток на сервере плохой тон, так как могут возникнуть конфликты. Конфликты должны решаться в локальных репозиториях.

Работа в простейшем случае выглядит примерно так. Вы вносите изменения в ветку develop (к примеру, добавили новый функционал, в котором уверены), сливаете ее с основной веткой master (создаете релиз) и отправляете ее на тестовый сервер (тестовую версию сайта) для проверки. На тестовом сервере вы стягиваете изменения и проверяете, если работоспособность вас устраивает, значит можно отправлять master и на основной сервер.

Comment: вот, кстати, вспомнил статью по ветвлению в git http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/